# How to write a unit test case for a search in the react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component which has an input box which is like->

```
class search extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.staate = {
            search : ''
        }
    }

     onInputChnage = (e) => {
        this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
     }

    render() {

        const { jobs: { content } } = this.props;
        const { search } = this.state;
        const filteredList = content.filter(job => (job.jdName && job.jdName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) || (job.technology && job.technology.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())));

        return (
            <input type="text"
                id="searchJob"
                className="form-control-sm border-0 flex-grow-1"
                value={this.state.search}
                placeholder="Technology / Job title"
                onChange={this.onInputChnage}
            />
            <i className="fa fa-search search-job"></i>
        )
    }
}
```

In this component, Now I have data about jobs which is coming from a reducer .

```
this.props.jobs = {
    "content": [{
        "id": "5b7d4a566c5fd00507501051",
        "companyId": null,
        "jdName": "Senior/ Lead UI Developer",
        "jobDescription": null,
        "technology": "java"
    },{
        "id": "5b7d4a566c5fd005075011",
        "companyId": null,
        "jdName": "ead UI Developer",
        "jobDescription": null,
        "technology": "angular"
    }]
}
```

Now, Here I want to test this component's search functionality using the unit test cases. I am using the `jest`. Now, Can anyone please help me with this? Any hint will be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: It would be great, if you could show us what you tried out, else the question seems very broad.

Comment: Duplicated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57953019/6463558